# Generate dictionary of points on n-sphere

Tags: python, performance, random, hash-map, numerical-methods

This is a long-shot, but my question is to simply optimize this particular function in some code I have written:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

def getSpherePoint(dim,pList,psetLen):
    npgauss = np.random.standard_normal
    pt = abs(np.random.standard_normal(psetLen))
    pt = pt/np.sqrt(inner1d(pt,pt))

    d = dict(zip(pList,pt))
    return d
```

Note that `dim` is some integer \$n\$, `pList` is simply a list of \$2^n-1\$ strings, and `psetLen` is \$2^n-1\$. This function is designed to return a dictionary keyed  by elements of `pList` with values determined by a point on the unit \$n\$-hypersphere.

At this point, I need to run this function around a billion times or so to get the results I want, which will take hours. I've done as much optimization as possible here, and my micro-optimization seems to indicate that all three major parts of the function (the random number, the normalization, and the dictionary association) all take approximately a third of the run-time, and I'm not sure how to reduce it further. I've squeezed a bit out of Cythoning it, but I'm not sure how much of an improvement that will give me as compared to actually writing it in C and then importing the C function. Unfortunately, I don't know C (or C++) and haven't written Java in years, so I'm pretty stuck using Python (or extensions thereof).

Is it possible to optimize this further by any significant factor? Would changing languages help dramatically? What improvements could be made in Python?

Comment: Why is `npgauss` never called?

Comment: Typo! My bad - doesn't need to be there anymore. Edited to reflect the change.

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: Right, sorry! Won't happen again!

Answer (score 4):

## Style

Following PEP8, the official Python style guide, you should use *snake_case* for your variables and functions names. You should also put a space after comas.

I would also rename the function `sphere_points` as the "get" is implied by the fact that you call a function (to get a result).

You also happen to not use the `dim` parameter and, looking at your description, the last one is just `len(pList)`. Unless this length is common to a lot of calls and there is a real benefit to cache it, you can drop 2 out of 3 parameters.

## `numpy`

`numpy` has vectorized functions  for your main operations: `numpy.fabs` (or `numpy.absolute` if you're dealing with complex numbers) and `numpy.linalg.norm`. Using these might speed things up. Unfortunately, going back into pure Python realm (`dict` + `zip`) can't be speed up that way.

However, as pointed out by @200_success in a comment, [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184560/1157100) suggest using `np.sqrt(pt.dot(pt))` or `np.sqrt(np.einsum('i,i', pt, pt))` for faster results than `np.linalg.norm`. As always, profile and choose what's best for your use case.

## Cache function access

In Python, local symbols are faster to resolve. Which means `np.linalg.norm` is kinda slow, but `norm` is faster. And granted you performed `norm = np.linalg.norm` somehow before, it will produce the same result.

But caching a complex lookup within the same call you use it does not add much, since the complex lookup still need to be performed.

One way to efficiently do it is to use default values for arguments as the lookup will be performed only once and the speedup will occur at each call.

## Proposed improvements

```
import numpy as np


def sphere_points(keys, random_gen=np.random.standard_normal, absolute=np.fabs, norm=np.linalg.norm):
    pt = absolute(random_gen(len(keys)))
    pt = pt/norm(pt)

    return dict(zip(keys, pt))
```

Comment: Right, I definitely left some typos in there. Should have checked before posting code. Yes, dim used to be used but it's not anymore. I added the length as an input because it's a defined variable that is constant for all of the calls, so I figured I would only call len(keys) once and then pass that to the function a billion times rather than calculate the length a billion times. Minute change, but I think it should be relevant, no? Also - I checked myself, the `inner1d` does speed up the calculation, so I should use that over norm, no?

Comment: @SamBlitz Definitely yes for `len(keys)`. Odd for `linalg.norm`, I don't see why it would be slower than `inner1d` as they should perform the same computation but `norm` is more specialized. But if your profiling data says otherwise, keep the faster.

Comment: According this [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9184560/1157100), `np.linalg.norm()` is indeed slower.